# How to remove the time from datetime from the calendar text box after tabbing out in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datetime, c#-4.0

[image: datetime]**The below code worked fine in .Net 3.5, but in .Net 4.0 a time is appering on calendar text box after tabbing out.**  when the focus is on the calendar text box, time doesnot apper. only after tabbing out time appears which is as shown in attached image. I dint want time part in that.

The code used is as follows:

```
<jkdp:XamDateTimeEditor Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                        InvalidValueBehavior="RetainValue"
                        gcb:CommandBehavior.Event="LostFocus"
                        gcb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding EndDateChangedCommand}"
                        Style="{DynamicResource XamDateTimeEditor.SimpleStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true}" >

<Style x:Key="XamDateTimeEditor.SimpleStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type igdEd:XamDateTimeEditor}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource XamDateTimeEditor.DefaultFromStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="10,0,10,0" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
            Value="{StaticResource CutCopyPasteEditorStyle}" />

    <Setter Property="vw:InputBindingBehaviour.EnableErrorToolTip"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="False"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop"
            Value="False"></Setter>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Focusable="False"
                      KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Name="PART_TextBox"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Focusable="True"
                             KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
                             Margin="0,0,2,0"
                             Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                             ContextMenu="{Binding Path=ContextMenu, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="PART_TextBlock"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Focusable="False"
                               KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="3,0,2,0"
                               Text="{Binding Path=NullText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Visibility="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NullConverter}, ConverterParameter=Visibility}" />
                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                                  MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Image Source="Calendar.bmp"
                               Focusable="False"
                               KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                               Margin="2" />
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NullConverter}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_TextBox"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="EditTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igdEd:XamDateTimeEditor}">
                <Grid   Focusable="False"
                        KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <igdEd:XamDateTimeEditor x:Name="PART_DateTimeEditor"
                                             BorderThickness="0"
                                             Background="Transparent"
                                             Focusable="False"
                                             KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                             Theme="{Binding Path=Theme, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             NullText="{Binding Path=NullText, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             DataMode="{Binding Path=DataMode, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             InvalidValueBehavior="{Binding Path=InvalidValueBehavior, Mode=OneTime, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             IsDropDownOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=PART_ToggleButton, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             ValueConstraint="{Binding Path=ValueConstraint, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                             ContextMenu="{Binding Path=ContextMenu, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    <vw:CommitTextBox x:Name="PART_FocusSite"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Focusable="True"
                             KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
                             MaxLength="10"
                             Margin="0,0,2,0"
                             Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeConverter}, ConverterParameter=DateFromStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                             ContextMenu="{Binding Path=ContextMenu, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                             Style="{StaticResource TextBox.NormalStyle}"/>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_ToggleButton"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                                  MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <Image   Focusable="False"
                                     KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                                     Source="Calendar.bmp"
                                     Margin="2" />
                        </ToggleButton.Content>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Code is not shown. Can you provide less code and be more specific - what exactly doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the DLLs on this machine to verify my answer, but according to [Infragistics' help](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamDateTimeEditor.html) you should set the Mask property to {date}. If I understand correctly from [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamMaskedEditor~Mask.html), it should look something like this:

```
<jkdp:XamDateTimeEditor 
                    .....
                    Mask="{}{date}"
                    ..... />
```

If you want to use the same Mask for all controls that are using this style, add this setter to the style:

```
<Setter Property="Mask" Value="{}{date}"/>
```

This will force the editor to use the short date mask as defined by the culture of the application. You can devise your own mask based on the StringFormat conventions explained in [MSDN's Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)